# What VNC client for Mac and/or Windows can I use to connect to “Screen Sharing” on Fedora and Ubuntu (desktop OSes)?

Tags: remote-access, remote-desktop

The only app I've found that works is Remmina, but of course that only runs on Linux. Apparently the issue is with encryption, which I don't even need because all traffic is staying on my LAN (behind my pfSense firewall). So, although it's not idea, I could just disable VNC encryption, but I haven't found a way to do so as of yet.

For Win/Mac VNC clients so far I've tried:

- uVNC client
- RealVNC Viewer (aka VNC Connect)
- Default "Screen Sharing.app" on macOS

None of them work. **What app on Mac and/or Windows meets the encryption standards that Fedora and/or Ubuntu are using for the baked in "Screen Sharing"?**

Answer (score 0):

Try [Anydesk](https://anydesk.com/en/downloads). I guess this may help you.

It works cross-platform and you can configure it to work on your local network.

Comment: Thanks, @Atif Ali. I'm not looking for a 3rd party solution like this, however. I have used TeamViewer and it does work fine, but I want a VNC client that will work with the default/built-in "Screen Sharing" feature of Fedora and/or Ubuntu Linux (Desktop GUI OS).